# MySQL Query Optimization - Grouping Values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

Ok this is my database structure:

```
TABLE `books`
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `title` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  `author` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)

TABLE `chapters`
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `book_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  `number` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  `title` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  KEY `book_id` (`book_id`) -> Foreign on `books`.`id`

TABLE `pages`
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `book_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  `chapter_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  `number` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' // real number, for page 1 of book 1 this has value 1, for page 1 of book 2 this has value 1...
  `value` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  KEY `book_id` (`book_id`) -> Foreign on `books`.`id`
  KEY `chapter_id` (`chapter_id`)  -> Foreign on `chapters`.`id`
```

Now... on a PHP page I would like to display the average `pages.value` for every book, the average `pages.value` for every chapter of every book and the single `pages.value` for every page:

```
Book 1 AVG = X
Book 1 Chapter   1            AVG = X
Book 1 Chapter ...            AVG = X
Book 1 Chapter   N            AVG = X
Book 1 Chapter   1 Page   1   VAL = X
Book 1 Chapter   1 Page ...   VAL = X
Book 1 Chapter   1 Page   N   VAL = X

And so on...
```

Of course, using 3 queries and some joins would be quite simple, and I could reformat data fitting my needs programmatically using PHP. 
But I would like to know if it's possible to optimize those queries (which are very slow to execute, by the way) into a single one, or maybe reduce the processing time by using advanced syntax.

Comment: GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP would presumably give you what you want - or you could do the final calculation in PHP. Presumably, all pages belong to a chapter?

Comment: Value is a column containing floats. It doesn't matter what. Pages belong to multiple chapters.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Alas, `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP` won't do the correct calculation for averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `ROLLUP`, but as Gordon points out, this *may* not return the average values that you expect. It depends on how you define those aggregations. However, I suspect that MySQL *does* define those averages in the way that you would expect. Here's an example, which succinctly illustrates both how to answer a question AND how to ask one (and possibly identifies flaws in this approach, which others can criticize)...

```
CREATE TABLE pages
(page_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,book VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,chapter_no INT NOT NULL
,page_no INT NOT NULL
,words INT NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(book,chapter_no,page_no)
);

INSERT INTO pages (book,chapter_no,page_no,words) VALUES
('The Hobbit',1,1,50),
('The Hobbit',1,2,60),
('The Hobbit',1,3,100),
('The Hobbit',1,4,40),
('The Hobbit',2,1,60),
('The Hobbit',2,2,40),
('The Hobbit',2,3,20),
('Oliver Twist',1,1,120),
('Oliver Twist',1,2,30),
('Oliver Twist',1,3,30),
('Oliver Twist',2,1,100),
('Oliver Twist',2,2,50);

SELECT * 
  FROM pages 
 ORDER  
    BY book
      ,chapter_no
      , page_no;
+---------+--------------+------------+---------+-------+
| page_id | book         | chapter_no | page_no | words |
+---------+--------------+------------+---------+-------+
|       8 | Oliver Twist |          1 |       1 |   120 |
|       9 | Oliver Twist |          1 |       2 |    30 |
|      10 | Oliver Twist |          1 |       3 |    30 |
|      11 | Oliver Twist |          2 |       1 |   100 |
|      12 | Oliver Twist |          2 |       2 |    50 |
|       1 | The Hobbit   |          1 |       1 |    50 |
|       2 | The Hobbit   |          1 |       2 |    60 |
|       3 | The Hobbit   |          1 |       3 |   100 |
|       4 | The Hobbit   |          1 |       4 |    40 |
|       5 | The Hobbit   |          2 |       1 |    60 |
|       6 | The Hobbit   |          2 |       2 |    40 |
|       7 | The Hobbit   |          2 |       3 |    20 |
+---------+--------------+------------+---------+-------+

SELECT book
     , chapter_no
     , page_no
     , AVG(words) words_per_page 
  FROM pages 
 GROUP 
    BY book
     , chapter_no
     , page_no WITH ROLLUP;
+--------------+------------+---------+----------------+
| book         | chapter_no | page_no | words_per_page |
+--------------+------------+---------+----------------+
| Oliver Twist |          1 |       1 |       120.0000 |
| Oliver Twist |          1 |       2 |        30.0000 |
| Oliver Twist |          1 |       3 |        30.0000 |
| Oliver Twist |          1 |    NULL |        60.0000 |<-- avg words per page chapter 1
| Oliver Twist |          2 |       1 |       100.0000 |
| Oliver Twist |          2 |       2 |        50.0000 |
| Oliver Twist |          2 |    NULL |        75.0000 |<-- avg words per page chapter 2
| Oliver Twist |       NULL |    NULL |        66.0000 |<-- avg words per page entire book
| The Hobbit   |          1 |       1 |        50.0000 |
| The Hobbit   |          1 |       2 |        60.0000 |
| The Hobbit   |          1 |       3 |       100.0000 |
| The Hobbit   |          1 |       4 |        40.0000 |
| The Hobbit   |          1 |    NULL |        62.5000 |<-- avg words per page chapter 1
| The Hobbit   |          2 |       1 |        60.0000 |
| The Hobbit   |          2 |       2 |        40.0000 |
| The Hobbit   |          2 |       3 |        20.0000 |
| The Hobbit   |          2 |    NULL |        40.0000 |<-- avg words per page chapter 2
| The Hobbit   |       NULL |    NULL |        52.8571 |<-- avg words per page entire book
| NULL         |       NULL |    NULL |        58.3333 |<-- avg words per page all books
+--------------+------------+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Indexing columns that you expect to use for searching helps immensely. For example:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name(column_name);
```

Another way of accomplishing the same thing is this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX ( column_name );
```

This way Your query execution time will be fast...